# How to get a single column in android mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

How can i get a single column using using android. instead of getting everything from the database. i want to get only the column where full_name="john".

DataParser.jave

```
public class DataParser  extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer>{

Context c;
ListView lv;
String jsonData;

ProgressDialog pd;
ArrayList<Person> persons=new ArrayList<>();

public DataParser(Context c, ListView lv, String jsonData) {
    this.c = c;
    this.lv = lv;
    this.jsonData = jsonData;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Parse");
    pd.setMessage("Parsing...Please wait");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.parseData();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    pd.dismiss();
    if(result==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        //CALL ADAPTER TO BIND DATA
        CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(c,persons);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}



private int parseData()
{
    try {
        JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(jsonData);
        JSONObject jo=null;

        persons.clear();
        Person s=null;




        for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++) {


            jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);


            int id = jo.getInt("id");
            String name = jo.getString("full_name");
            String sex = jo.getString("sex");
            String location = jo.getString("location");


            s = new Person();
            s.setId(id);
            s.setFull_name(name);
            s.setSex(sex);
            s.setLocation(location);


            persons.add(s);



        }

                return 1;




    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

}

Downloader.java

```
public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

Context c;
String urlAddress;
ListView lv;

ProgressDialog pd;

public Downloader(Context c, String urlAddress, ListView lv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.urlAddress = urlAddress;
    this.lv = lv;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Fetch");
    pd.setMessage("Fetching....Please wait");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.downloadData();
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);

    pd.dismiss();

    if(s==null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(c,"Unsuccessfull,Null 
    returned",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else
    { 
        //CALL DATA PARSER TO PARSE
        DataParser parser=new DataParser(c,lv,s);
        parser.execute();

    }


}


private String downloadData()
{
    HttpURLConnection con=Connector.connect(urlAddress);
    if(con==null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    InputStream is=null;
    try {

        is=new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line=null;
        StringBuffer response=new StringBuffer();

        if(br != null)
        {
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                response.append(line+"\n");
            }

            br.close();

        }else
        {
            return null;
        }

        return response.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(is != null)
        {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    return null;
  }
 }
```

Connector.java

```
public class Connector {

public static HttpURLConnection connect(String urlAddress)
{
    try {
        URL url=new URL(urlAddress);
        HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //SET PROPS
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        con.setReadTimeout(20000);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        return con;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}


  }
```

Person.java

```
public class Person {
    int id;
String full_name, sex, location;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFull_name() {
    return full_name;
}

public void setFull_name(String full_name) {
    this.full_name = full_name;
}

public String getSex() {
    return sex;
}

public void setSex(String sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
```

}

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context c;
ArrayList<Person> persons;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Person> persons) {
    this.c = c;
    this.persons = persons;

    //INITIALIE
    inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return persons.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return persons.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return persons.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.model,parent,false);
    }

    TextView nameTxt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
    TextView sexTxt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.propellantTxt);
    TextView locationTxt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descTxt);

    nameTxt.setText(persons.get(position).getFull_name());
    sexTxt.setText(persons.get(position).getSex());
    locationTxt.setText(persons.get(position).getLocation());

    //ITEM CLICKS
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(c,persons.get(position).getFull_name(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

}

server side php file

```
<?php 

$host = 'localhost';
$username='root';
$pwd ='';
$db ='user';

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$pwd,$db) or die('Unable to connect');
if(mysqli_connect_error($con))
{
echo "Failed to Connect to Database ".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM person");
if($query)
{
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
$data[]=$row;
}
 print(json_encode($data));
}else
{
echo('Not Found ');
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String urlAddress="http://localhost/Android/includes/retrive.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);



    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Downloader d=new Downloader(MainActivity.this,urlAddress,lv);
            d.execute();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Got the code online and cant find a way to get a single column

Comment: Where do you query the data from mysql?

Comment: Have edited the post can check again please

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the json you are using is from an API response.  In that case, if you want to do it in SQL you would need to create a new api and SQL query on the server.  If you want to just limit what is displaying in the loop, only parse the parts you want.

```
for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++) {


        jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);


        int id = jo.getInt("id");
        String name = jo.getString("full_name");

        s = new Person();
        s.setFull_name(name);

        persons.add(s);



    }
```

You would then need to also change the logic in your activity that displays the data, and only display person.name, as the rest of the properties will be null.

I recommend doing more research on consuming APIs and parsing JSON, as it appears that the code you are using does not have a database or SQL.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, my problem is i want to display only the data with a specific name e.g display only where full_name="john". not everything in the database

Comment: Hello, have added the server side php to the question. thank you